# How can I change FlashVars parameters into a URL query string?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I understand that when retrieving an SWF file and passing parameters to that file while doing so, there are two options to do this: using the FlashVars or the query string technique.

Say I wish to obtain the swf file directly via HTTP so that I can download the file, and I know from the source code that the file, when embedded, is passed the the following parameters via FlashVars with the following Javascript code:

```
// used to validate hour parameter
            var numberOfSegments = 1;

            var flashvars1 = {};
            flashvars1.url = "http://cm.dce.harvard.edu/2014/02/23515/L12/23515-20140502-L12-H264HighBandwidthTalkingHead-16x9.xml";
            flashvars1.videoWidth = "374";
            flashvars1.videoHeight = "210";
            flashvars1.resizable = true;
flashvars1.hour = 1;
flashvars1.autoPlay = true;
flashvars1.largeTH = false;
flashvars1.cdn = false;


            //<!-- 
            // This will create or overwrite optional HOUR parameter
            // Tests if URL had query argument: "?part=3" 
            // Checking for part in range prevents flash #1006 error 
            if (location.search != ""){
                var queryStr = location.search.split('?');
                if(queryStr.length > 1){
                    queryStr = queryStr[1];
                    var queryArray = queryStr.split("&");
                    for ( var i = 0; i < queryArray.length; i++){
                        var pair = queryArray[i].split("=");
                        if ((pair[0] == "part") && (pair.length > 1) && !isNaN(pair[1])){
                            if((numberOfSegments != null) && (0 < pair[1]) && (pair[1] <= numberOfSegments) ){
                                flashvars1.hour = pair[1];
                            } // make sure hour value is in range
                        } // end if HOUR is part of query 
                    }  // end query pair array loop
               }  // end if query has content
            } // end if query exists
            // -->
            var params1 = {};
            params1.quality = "high";
            params1.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
            params1.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
            params1.allowfullscreen = "true";
            params1.wmode = "transparent";

            var attributes1 = {};
            attributes1.id = "flashContent1";
            attributes1.name = "flashContent1";
            attributes1.align = "middle";

            swfobject.embedSWF(
                "/flash/FlashViewer.swf", "flashContent1", 
                "100%", "100%", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars1, params1, attributes1);
```

How then do I translate FlashVars into a query string I can append at the end of the swf URL?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the a query string with all the values from the flashvars1 JSON object:

```
var querystring = "?";
for (var key in flashvars1) {
  if (flashvars1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    querystring += key + "=" + flashvars[key] + "&";
  }
}
```